# issue in using inperson Signing in docusign, page redirects after 1st signer signs

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am using Docusign for Digital signature in the contract in my website.
I want my clients to sign instantly after meeting is closed and both party
will sign one by one at the end of meeting.

So i am using In Person Signer option.
I need 2 signs from two clients in the contract, so i have set 2 In Person
Signer recipients in my code.

But when i sign the document for 1st signer, and ready to sign for 2nd
Signer, the page redirects to the success page (that i set in my script)
without allowing to sign for the 2nd recipient. How will i get both signers
sign and then complete the contract.

If i am doing anything wrong, i am attaching the code.

This is the code:

`\"recipients\":{
    \"inPersonSigners\":[
    {
    \"hostEmail\":\"$username\",
    \"hostName\":\"Priya Ranjan Jena\",
    \"recipientId\":\"2\",
    \"signerName\":\"Rajesh ultra Sahoo\",
    \"rountingOrder\":\"1\", 
    \"tabs\":{
    \"signHereTabs\":[
    {
    \"xPosition\":\"90\",
    \"yPosition\":\"590\",
    \"documentId\":\"1\",
    \"pageNumber\":\"4\"
    }
    ]
    }
    },
    {
    \"hostEmail\":\"$username\",
    \"hostName\":\"Priya Ranjan Jena\",
    \"recipientId\":\"1\",
    \"signerName\":\"Maitreya Kumar Tripathi\",
    \"rountingOrder\":\"2\", 
    \"tabs\":{
    \"signHereTabs\":[
    {
    \"xPosition\":\"390\",
    \"yPosition\":\"590\",
    \"documentId\":\"1\",
    \"pageNumber\":\"4\"
    }
    ]
    }
    }
    ]
    }`

Answer (score 0):

For every signing session you will need to get a recipient view.  Per your description the system is behaving per spec.

```
Step 1: you create the envelope with 2 recipients
Step 2: you request an embedded view for 1st recipient
Step 3: upon completion the signer is redirected to your return URL
```

To get to 2nd person's signing you will need to do the following:

```
Step 4: request the embedded view for the 2nd recipient
Step 5: get control when that embedded view returns.
```

Hope this makes sense.

-mb